# TokenMismatchException when deleting a row in db

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, token, csrf-protection

I'm using DropZone.js and laravel. When i try to delete a record with an AJAX request i get a response saying:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong. 1/1 TokenMismatchException in
>   VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
var classElements = document.querySelectorAll("tr.ui-selected td.filename");

        for(var x = 0;x < classElements.length;x++){
            var result;
            result = classElements[x].innerHTML;
            var csrf = $('input[name=_token]').val();
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                type: "DELETE",
                method: 'POST',
                url: '../public/deletefile',
                data: { filename: result, "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"  },
                success: function(response) {
                   $('#results').html(response);
                }
            });
```

This is the model:

```
public function deleteUserFiles(){ 
        $userid = Auth::id();
        $result = $_POST['result'];
        $deletedRows = App\Models\File::where('filename', $result)->where('userid', $userid)->delete();
    }
}
```

And the route:

```
Route::post('deletefile', 'UserFiles@deleteUserFiles');
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you use `csrf_token()` in loop. I think your JS code should look like this:

```
var classElements = document.querySelectorAll("tr.ui-selected td.filename");
var csrf = $('input[name=_token]').val();

for(var x = 0;x < classElements.length;x++){
    var result;
    result = classElements[x].innerHTML;

    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: "DELETE",
        method: 'POST',
        url: '../public/deletefile',
        data: { filename: result, "_token": csrf  },
        success: function(response) {
           $('#results').html(response);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yep, that was the problem.Thanks. I thought that it should loop too